# Simple batch file fails on Windows Server 2012

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012, powershell-3.0

On a Windows 2012 Server, from a logged-in Administrator (local and domain), created a batch file "test.bat" by redirecting console input into a file:

```
echo Hello
```

When run from PowerShell cmd prompt as `.\test.bat`, it echoes:

```
'■e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Batch file is in logged-in user's C:\users\%username% directory.

The file was created from console, thus:

```
echo "echo Hello" > test.bat
```

and then edited with Notepad. Looked alright in Notepad... nothing unusual.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

EDITED:

Per suggestion, I modified command line input to remove quotes. Therefore, entered the command like this: `echo echo Yowzer > test.bat`  Ran as: `.\test.bat` and got the same response as above. Also note that if I edit in Notepad the above test.bat (i.e. created at cmd line) and re-run, it still returns a garbage response. However, if I create/save the file in Notepad ***from the start,*** it works correctly.

Can anyone duplicate this?

Comment: "C:\users\%username%"?? not in subdir like documents? did you cd into the folder that contains the bat file and then run ".\test bat"? And you are executing this from a poweshell console right?

Comment: The bat file was both created and run from C:\subdir. Two methods were used to create the bat file: (1) `echo stuff > bat.bat` from keyboard, and (2) write in Notepad++ and save as bat file. All cmd prompt activity was done from a PoSH console.

Comment: -1 for abandoning the question, thus decreasing its value

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the redirect `>` has encoded your batch file in unicode, when it should be ascii. In Powershell, use `Out-File` instead of the redirect like this:

```
"echo test" | Out-File test.bat -Encoding ascii
```

Running the batch file after the following encoding will reproduce the error:

```
"echo test" | Out-File test.bat -Encoding unicode
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, thought I was crazy.

Make your batch file on another computer.  I had the same issue opening Notepad and typing the commands normally.  It always gave me the same message.  Once I recreated the batch file (do not copy the old file) on my local Win7 device, copied it back to my Win 2012R2 server, worked like a champ.

Comment: I have no idea why, but this worked for me in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have some funny character somewhere. I'm pretty sure that if you do `xxd -p blah.bat` then you will see some funny characters in your batch file.

You could then think about how they got there, and removing them.. And that can be done with xxd and sed. Or perhaps another way, if you know what characters they are.

You can get xxd from downloading VIM 7.X, or from cygwin

Or you could find a hex editor and put the batch file in the hex editor.

You say you are creating the batch file from stdin.. Well, you could elaborate on precisely what you mean by that e.g. do you mean by `copy con blah.bat` then CTRL-Z?  But whatever way you mean, it is putting some funny chars in the file.

**added**

I see you state that you did it with echo and redirect..

You can easily simplify this for some troubleshooting

Try  `type blah.bat`

if that shows a funny character then try
`echo H>blah.bat` then build it up to what you typed.. and see at what point you get the funny character.

Another thing to experiment with is input and output encoding

try chcp.  chcp 850  and chcp 65001 and see if you see any differences.   chcp will change both input and output encoding, but chcp will only show you the input encoding.

If you look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904504/font-is-right-why-cant-i-get-this-unicode-character-to-display-in-this-c-sharp/32418703#32418703    you see a program called chcpa that I wrote a while back, and you can use that to change input and output encodings more flexibly than chcp can.  Or you could just use chcp but if you find chcp is limiting you in your troubleshooting then you could try chcpa.

But one of your best tools here in your troubleshooting would be a hex editor or xxd as mentioned. And trying to simplify your line even further, as suggested.

Steps like that will help you isolate where the error is. And comment when you try anything here or further.

Answer (score -1):

Echo doesnt use quotation marks.  Take out the double quotes and it will work.

```
echo echo hello > test.bat
```

Echo looks for the string after echo and the space, the quotes break the string.

More on [echo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx).

Comment: That did not fix the problem.  Inputted: `echo echo Yowzer > test.bat`  Ran as: `.\test.bat` and still got the same response as above. Note that if I edit the file in Notepad, it still returns a garbage response. However, if I create/save the file in Notepad from the start, all is well. Can anyone duplicate this?

Comment: strange.  it worked for me.

Comment: Were you able to replicate the problem I was having? That is, did you see the weird result reported above when using quote marks?

Comment: yes.  I removed the quotes and it worked as intended

Comment: -1 He said "were you able to replicate the problem I was having"  And the problem he was having was was those funny characters. And you replied saying "yes...".   And it's clear from his question and even more clear from his reply, that what you speak of "the quotes break the string", is absolutely and obviously not the problem