# I've got a batch file that works great on my Windows PC but won't work at all on my Windows server

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, batch, video-conversion

I've written a batch file that uses ffmpeg to compress 1080p videos from my camera to 720p videos (using 2 passes) for my website. It works great on my Windows PC at home but when I attempt to use it on my Windows 2012 server, it does nothing. Here's the batch file I wrote:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -y -i ^"%%a^" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -vf "scale=1280:-2" -preset fast -pass 1 -an -f mp4 NUL && ^
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i ^"%%a^" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -vf "scale=1280:-2" -preset fast -pass 2 -c:a copy ^"converted/%%~na.mp4^
```

I would like to get this working on my server so I can edit my friends videos for them as well. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you right clicked on it and select run as admin?

Comment: I did, unfortunately

Comment: Server 2102 is locked down, there may be a group policy setting preventing you from running bat files. I assume ffmpeg is installed.

Comment: ffmpeg was opened up when I got the server (cleared it with the server company before I got a slot) and runs great for every other process I've used it for.

Comment: I would assume you’re never executing the for loops. You need to do basic troubleshooting in your batch file. If the batch file is starting it’s not doing “nothing” it simply isn’t doing what you think it is.

Comment: Adding a pause would let you see if it's indeed doing something or not.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed Windows 10 Notepad default encoding is UTF-8. Server 2012 R2 Notepad default encoding is ANSI. What this means is the modifications to batch script file might input weird characters causing issues. Not sure this IS your issue, but it doesn't hurt to check. Easy fix: copy or type commands from working script into a new notepad window in 2012 to confirm no weird conversion is happening. Similar question that seems to elude this is the cause:
[Simple batch file fails on Windows Server 2012](https://superuser.com/q/775314/160219)